# SAS fill gap in serial numbers

Tags: sas

I have a dataset `&RAWDATA` that's similar to the following sample:

```
| Symbol | Date     | Time | BB | BO | MIDPRICE |
|--------|----------|------|----|----|----------|
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 2    | 2  | 3  | 2.5      |
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 3    | 1  | 3  | 1.5      |
| ...    |          |      |    |    |          |
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 100  | 3  | 4  |  3.5     |
| FB     | 20130102 | 1    | 3  | 6  | 4.5      |
| FB     | 20130102 | 3    | 3  | 5  | 4        |
| ...    |          |      |    |    |          |
| FB     | 20130102 | 100  | 3  | 4  |  3.5     |
```

There is only one row for each Symbol at a specific time.

Now, I want to process this dataset so that the **time variable starts from 1 and is continuous**. If there is no record at a specific time, then create a new record at that time, set all values to the previous record.

The correct output should be something like:

```
| Symbol | Date     | Time | BB | BO | MIDPRICE |
|--------|----------|------|----|----|----------|
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 1    | 2  | 3  | 2.5      |
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 2    | 2  | 3  | 2.5      |
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 3    | 1  | 3  | 1.5      |
| ...    |          |      |    |    |          |
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 100  | 3  | 4  |  3.5     |
| FB     | 20130102 | 1    | 3  | 6  | 4.5      |
| FB     | 20130102 | 2    | 3  | 6  | 4.5      |
| FB     | 20130102 | 3    | 3  | 5  | 4        |
| ...    |          |      |    |    |          |
| FB     | 20130102 | 100  | 3  | 4  |  3.5     |
```

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work well:

```
/*
 * Macro to fill in the gap seconds
 */
%MACRO GAP_SEC(RAWDATA);
  data GAPDATA;
    SET &RAWDATA; by symbol date; 
    retain SYMBOL DATE TIME BB BO MIDPRICE;
    LAG_SYMBOL = lag(SYMBOL);
    LAG_DATE = lag(DATE);
    LAG_TIME = lag(TIME);
    LAG_BB = lag(BB);
    LAG_BO = lag(BO);
    LAG_MIDPRICE = lag(MIDPRICE);
    if first.symbol and first.date then 
   DO;
    if TIME NE 1; 
    N = TIME - 1; 
    DO WHILE(N>1);
    SYMBOL=SYMBOL;
    BB=BB;
    BO=BO;
    MIDPRICE = MIDPRICE;
    TIME=TIME-1;
    output;
    n=n-1;
    END;
   END;
else 
do;
    TIME_DIFF = TIME - LAG_TIME;
    if TIME_DIFF > 1 then 
        DO;
            M=TIME_DIFF;
            DO WHILE(M>1);
              SYMBOL = LAG_SYMBOL;
              TIME = TIME + 1;
              DATE = LAG_DATE;
              BB = LAG_BB;
              BO = LAG_BO;
              MIDPRICE = LAG_MIDPRICE;
              output;
              M=M-1;
            END;  
        END;
    end;
    drop LAG_SYMBOL LAG_DATE LAG_TIME LAG_BB LAG_BO LAG_MIDPRICE TIME_DIFF N M;
  run;
  /* Add new obs to original data set */
  proc append base=&RAWDATA data=GAPDATA;
  run;
  proc sort data=&RAWDATA force; by Symbol Date Time; run;
%mend;
```

It will not fill the gap, and it also generate duplicate records with the same time and same symbol. (Note that in the original dataset, there is only one record for each symbol at a specific time). For example, the dataset might become:

```
| Symbol | Date     | Time | BB | BO | MIDPRICE |
|--------|----------|------|----|----|----------|
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 2    | 2  | 3  | 2.5      |
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 2    | 2  | 3  | 2.5      |
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 3    | 1  | 3  | 1.5      |
| ...    |          |      |    |    |          |
| AAPL   | 20130102 | 100  | 3  | 4  |  3.5     |
| FB     | 20130102 | 1    | 3  | 6  | 4.5      |
| FB     | 20130102 | 1    | 3  | 6  | 4.5      |
| FB     | 20130102 | 3    | 3  | 5  | 4        |
| ...    |          |      |    |    |          |
| FB     | 20130102 | 100  | 3  | 4  |  3.5     |
```

What I did wrong here?

Besides, **I also want all symbols end at the same time**. For example, the max time can go is 100 - it cannot increase infinitely.

**UPDATE:**

If there is no record for time 1, I am thinking to ignore it first, and do something in the later code:

```
  set &RAWDATA; by Symbol;
    if not missing(Symbol);
    /* retain the price from last second */
    retain MIDPRICE CUM_RETURN; 
    LAG_MIDPRICE = lag(MIDPRICE);
    LAG_CUMRETURN = lag(CUM_RETURN);
    /* Make sure we are calculating the same ticker*/
    return_sec = (MIDPRICE - LAG_MIDPRICE) / LAG_MIDPRICE;
    if first.symbol then 
    do;
      CUM_RETURN = 0;
      return_sec = 0;
    end;
    CUM_RETURN  = sum(CUM_RETURN, return_sec);
    RMIN = 0.01/MIDPRICE;
    drop LAG_MIDPRICE LAG_CUMRETURN BB BO MIDPRICE CUM_RETURN RMIN;
  run;
```

As you can see, I am calculating the returns for the symbols later. So, if there is no time 1, instead of setting the BB, BO or MIDPRICE to 0, I want to set the return_sec of time 1 to 0 until the first record appears.

Comment: will there always be a time=1 record for each symbol/date combo?  If not, what values should be listed for the time records before the first?

Comment: Actually, let me update the question.

Comment: @DomPazz Updated.

Comment: Do you have a license for SAS/ETS? Run `proc setinit; run;` to check. If you do, you'll want to look into PROC TIMESERIES to create a valid time series for you. Obviously you can do this manually via data step but it's more efficient in TIMESERIES.

Comment: @Reeza `---SAS/ETS
                        31JUL2017`

Comment: Then I would suggest looking into PROC TIMESERIES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PROC EXPAND` from SAS/ETS.  That allows you to expand a series.  The `METHOD=STEP` option will carry the last non-missing value forward.

I modified the example data for FB to test a variable that does not end at 100.

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter="|";
informat symbol $6.
         date anydtdte.;
format date date9.;
input Symbol $ Date time bid offer mid;
datalines;
AAPL   | 20130102 | 2    | 2  | 3  | 2.5      
AAPL   | 20130102 | 3    | 1  | 3  | 1.5      
AAPL   | 20130102 | 100  | 3  | 4  |  3.5     
FB     | 20130102 | 1    | 3  | 6  | 4.5      
FB     | 20130102 | 3    | 3  | 5  | 4        
FB     | 20130102 | 90  | 3  | 4  |  3.5     
;
```

This data step adds the values from the last value up to 100.

```
data have;
set have;
by symbol date;

if last.date then do;
    if time ^= 100 then do;
        do time=time to 100;
            output;
        end;
    end;
    else 
        output;
end;
else
    output;
run;
```

`PROC EXPAND` fills in the gaps.

```
proc expand data=have out=want to=day method=step;
by symbol date;
id time;
convert bid;
convert offer;
convert mid;
run;
```

`PROC EXPAND` tries to be helpful and set time to a date.  Just change the format.

```
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
modify want;
format time best.;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: What does best. do?

Comment: It is a SAS format.  Best number format available.  Formats are just how SAS presents the values for display.

Comment: `best number format available` not quite.  `BESTw.` chooses the "best" decimal precision possible for each number (meaning a column may have values on various rows shown at different precisions).  That's all.

Comment: But why do you use to=day? I am a little bit confused by the unit here.

Comment: Besides, what if i want to fill in the gap between 1 and the first non-1 elements? @DomPazz I am trying `if last.date then do;
    if time ^= 1 then do;
        do time=1 to time;
            output;
        end;
    end;
    else
        output;
end;` but it seems that it doesn't work well.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.  Give me a data example that doesn't work with the code above.  My code does what you are asking based on how I understand what you want.  The option `to=day` tells PROC EXPAND to think of the `ID` variable as a day, which are integers.  Your `TIME` variable is an integer.

Comment: @Joe  YES Yes yes.  `bestw.` gives you the best with precision w.  `best.` gives you the best format for the default precision (12).

Comment: More trying to say that it's not going to give a "different" format, like a date or something.  I read "best format" as some attempt to actually figure out the data type.  `best` just guesses where to put the decimal, nothing more.

Comment: @DomPazz If I leave the convert statement, SAS will automatically convert all numeric variables (except the ones used in id and by statements), right?